# WinObjC: troubles when converting

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, winobjc

Good day! I became interested in the tool from Microsoft vsimporter. There was such a problem: when I try to convert .xcodeproj project .sln project in the command line the message appears "The "project" workspace does not contain any schemes". All the schemes are in place. This problem occurs randomly, because It succeded to convert two projects, but with the other two the problem above. I can not understand because of what it happens. If anyone faced with an identical problem I will be glad to any hint!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is likely due to the presence of CocoaPods – was your Xcode workspace file generated by CocoaPods? The bridge currently does not support CocoaPods because of limitations in its clang compiler front end, but it's a request we get a lot so we're investigating adding support. Try removing CocoaPods and including your third-party libraries manually. If you run into issues, feel free to get in touch by filing [an issue on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/issues) – it's the best way to talk directly to our team. Thanks for checking out the bridge!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't use cocoapods for that project, and it doesn't have any workspace. Okay, I will try to ask on GitHub @NickGerard